# PhantomJS Project in Eclipse (with Nodeclipse): NullPointerException when trying to run js file that is present in a folder

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, phantomjs, nodeclipse

I wish to create a PhantomJS Project in Eclipse for which I have installed the Nodeclipse PhantomJS 0.12+ plugin. I am selecting the below project type:

[image]

The script **runs fine** when I arrange the project in the following way (without any folders).

[image]

But, when I place the same .js file in a folder and try to run it, I end up getting a NullPointerException (see screenshot below).

[image]

The error that I'm getting is below:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching PhantomJSTest-Test1.js".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**What I have tried**:
I found a similar question on Stackoverflow with the same error but for Android. I have tried cleaning, building the project. But, the error occurs only when I create a folder structure in my project. If I don't, then the script runs fine. In short, I am not able to organize the project.

**Questions**:

1. I'd like to know what type of **folder structure** is valid / will work for a PhantomJS project?
2. Why is the NullPointerException occuring?
3. Are there any other **easy** alternatives to setting up a PhantomJS project?

Any help / guidance regarding the folder structure is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using **Enide Studio** and that solved the folder structure issue for me.

Here's what is needed to setup PhantomJS Project:

1. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)
2. [Enide Studio](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/)

**Steps**:

1. Download PhantomJS
2. Download and launch Enide Studio
3. Goto *Window->Preferences->Nodeclipse->PhantomJS* and set PhantomJS Path to 'phantomjs.exe' file path

[image]

4. Create a PhantomJS Project (like any normal project)

Answer (score 1):

First get the latest version, that is 0.17, see news/history at http://www.nodeclipse.org/

If the problem is still on, raise issue on https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/ (and reference this question)

To the questions:

1. PhantomJS launcher is rather simple https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.phantomjs, and it should work for any .js file (in any project type). PhantomJS project type is for beauty sake only, as it is just JavaScript project.
2. NullPointerException should occur never, so it may be bug.
3. You can create general project as well. But with JSDT and Tern you would get some Content Assist. For new module support with Tern raise issue at https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked the Nodeclipse plugin version and I had v0.17. I uninstalled and re-installed again and the issue is still happening. I've raised issue #188 and gave a reference to this question - https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/188.